# Not generating expected results between google calendar and spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, calendar

So I have some code to create calendar events based on a jobs sheet for meetings but I can't seem to get it working as I would expect- I have columns 24 and 25 to keep track of if its been put in the calendar and the calendar event id, I don't want it to delete then create a new event for ones that have already been added (as this spreadsheet can get large) so thats why I keep track via on edit. But is seems to create a new event every time. If anyone can have a look over that would be great as I've been struggling for the past 3 days with this.
Many thanks

```
//push new events to calendar;

function pushToCalendar() {

  //spreadsheet variables
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,26);
  var values = range.getValues();   
  var updateRange = sheet.getRange('Z1');

  //calendar variables
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('insert calendar code here')

  //show updating message
  updateRange.setFontColor('red');

  var numValues = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {   

    //check to see if name are filled out
    if ((values[i][0].length > 0) && (values[i][1].length > 0)) {

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// if it has been edited delete old event  

       if (values[i][23] ='n') {   
         try{
           var eventIdCell =values[i][24];
           var eventId =calendar.getEventSeriesById(eventIdCell);
           eventId.deleteEventSeries();
       } 
        catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to delete if it has been edited and the old event if it still exists
        }
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

      //check if it's been entered before          
      if (values[i][23] !='y') {  

        var newEventTitle = values[i][0] + ' - ' + values[i][1]+' - ' + 'Sample';         
        var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(newEventTitle, new Date(values[i][6]));

        //get ID
        var newEventId = newEvent.getId();

        //mark as entered, enter ID
        sheet.getRange(i+2,24).setValue('y');
        sheet.getRange(i+2,25).setValue(newEventId);

      }
    }

    numValues++;
    }

  //hide updating message
  updateRange.setFontColor('white');
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//add a menu when the spreadsheet is opened
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];  
  menuEntries.push({name: "Update Calendar", functionName: "pushToCalendar"}); 
  sheet.addMenu("Jobs Calendar", menuEntries);  
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function onEdit(event){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
 var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell();
 var row = activeCell.getRow();

  if(row < 2){
    return; //If header row then return
  }
  else{
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var updateCalCell = actSht.getRange(index,24);
  var eventIdCell = actSht.getRange(index,25);

   change updated on colander status to n
  updateCalCell.setValue('n');
}
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: could you perhaps create a shared copy of your SS with some data to make it easier to test ?

Comment: sure heres the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RAtbzbrtDtMqO7ql_0V-EyWqxnuiycNOtUTIFXORDUw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple error in the condition : the EQUAL operator in comparison is `==` and not `=`, change that and it will work.

```
if (values[i][23] =='n') {
```

Comment: :D many thanks I was looking for the problem in the wrong place >< Many thanks